# JQuery passing number from function to other JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have some error handling function that I wish to return the amount of errors so I can handle within another function. However it's not working as expected. Anyone have any ideas?

```
function validateForm() {
        // error handling
        var errorCounter = 0;

        $(".required").each(function(i, obj) {

            if($(this).val() === ''){
                $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
                return errorCounter++;
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("has-error");
                return errorCounter;
            }

        });
    }
```

Other function:

```
function actionCreateInvoice(){

        validateForm(errorCounter);

        if (errorCounter > 0) {
            $("#response").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-warning").fadeIn();
            $("#response .message").html("<strong>Error</strong>: It appear's you have forgotten to complete something!");
        } else {
            ..... do something here once validated
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this `return errorCounter;` outside of `.each`.

```
function validateForm() {
    // error handling
    var errorCounter = 0;

    $(".required").each(function(i, obj) {

        if($(this).val() === ''){
            $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
            errorCounter++;
        } else{ 
            $(this).parent().removeClass("has-error"); 
        }


    });

    return errorCounter;
}
```

Call your function like this:

```
function actionCreateInvoice(){
     var errorCounter = validateForm();//do not pass errorCounter as parameter
```

Comment: @James call your function like this : `validateForm();`

Comment: Bingo! getting a 500 internal error on response.php but ill check that out but this is working now! thanks a bunch mate!

Comment: I wont forget dont worry, i just noticed its not add the error class... think that might be as its throwing 500 error back on the repsonse.php file?

Comment: Actually its skipping the validation now all together as trying to process the response.php on ajax any ideas?

Comment: @James I would create a new question with the new issue and include the `ajax` call.

Comment: Its not that, the validation is not working since we done var errorEncounter  part... its skipping validation and going straight to success in ajax

Comment: I done console log after var errorCounter = validateForm(); and it returns undefined

Comment: @James see the update I moved the ` return errorCounter;` outside of `each`